# C++ Moving elements from one vector to another

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, reference

I'm still learning the ropes of C++.

I want to move certain elements of a vector to another vector (based on whether the vector is contained in an unordered_set).

However, I keep getting an error that the vector class does not have an insert method that takes a reference variable. Specifically, this error:

```
In file included from TorrentTrackerCommManager.h:10:0,
                 from TorrentTrackerCommManager.cpp:1:
PeerList.h: In member function ‘void PeerList::addPeers(std::vector<Peer*>)’:
PeerList.h:51:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Peer>::insert(Peer&)’
      peerList.insert(*p);
```

The code I'm using is here:

```
class PeerList {

    private:

        /* List holding all of the Peer objects. */
        std::vector<Peer> peerList;

        /* Set holding all of the Peer objects. */
        std::unordered_set<Peer, PeerHash> peerSet;

    public:

         void addPeers(std::vector<Peer *> newPeers) {

            std::vector<Peer *>::iterator it;
            for (it = newPeers.begin(); it != newPeers.end(); ++it) {

                Peer p = **it;

                //If we don't already have that peer
                if (peerSet.find(p) != peerSet.end()) {

                    //add him
                    peerList.insert(p);
                    peerSet.insert(p);
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: vectors have `push_back`.

Comment: Be careful with your terminology.  You are not _moving_ the element from one vector to another, you are _copying_ it.  A move would be a very different operation.

Comment: Is this code pasted correctly? peerList is a vector of type <Peer>, while in addPeers() you iterator over <Peer *> (i.e. a pointer to Peer), but you're not de-referencing it while insert()ing it. So you may need to do peerList.insert (*p)/push_back(*p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::vector<...>` does have an `insert()` method. Actually, it has multiple overloaded `insert()` methods but all of them take an iterator indicating the position where to insert the passed value(s). If it is OK to append the value to the end, you can use `push_back()`:

```
peerList.push_back(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

For a vector, you need

```
peerList.push_back(p);
```

You can find a good overview table about container methods on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the documentations while you write your code, and here it is for the [std::vector::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert). This function requires the position that you are inserting so in your case you need to get the length of the vector and pass it to the function.

If you just want to add it to the end of the vector, you can use [std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) or [std::vector::emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) (for C++11). Since you tagged C++11 I assume you use C++11, and `emplace_back` is more recommended in your case. It takes the arguments and pass to the constructors too.

If you want to `move` an object from the old vector to the new one, you need to cast it to a `rvalue reference` or use [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) (which actually just does casting). So I suggest you do this:

```
peerList.emplace_back((Peer&&) p);
```

or

```
peerList.emplace_back(std::move(p));  // You need to include <utility>
```